# Android access files backed up in device through DDMS

Tags: java, android, ddms

How to access the files that are backed-up in Device, through DDMS? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Backed-up to where.., internal storage, SDCard..?

Comment: See @Brijesh Thakur's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "File Explorer". It is a part of DDMS View.

Using File Explorer you can View , Pull files from Device. Push files to Device and Delete files as well.

Comment: But how... Without knowing the path of the backup?

Comment: Without knowing the path means? It is expected that user should know where he wants to go. File Explored will help you to go there.